# Is there a way to create a user page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress there is an author.php template file that you can use to display author information.  I am wondering if there is a way to create a template file to display a users information (any role), even if they are not an author to any post, but is a registered user.  Something like http://domain.com/user/some_name

Answer (score 5):

a. Create a template called members.php and put code snippet like this on that file:

> ```
> global $wpdb;
> $query = "SELECT ID from $wpdb->users";
> $author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);
> $users = array();
> foreach($author_ids as $author) {
>    // Get user data
>    $curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);
>    // Get link to author page
>    $link = "/member/" . $curauth->user_nicename;
>    $name = $curauth->display_name;
>    $users[$link] = $name;
> }
> asort($users);
> ?>
> <ol>
> // Loop through each author
> <?php
> foreach($users as $link => $name) :
> ?>
> <li>
>    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php
>      echo $name; ?></a>
> </li>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> </ol>
> ```

b. Create a wordpress page called members using above template. This page will list all blog registered users with a ink to a page `/member/user-name`.

c. Now create your author.php template displaying user information with code snippet like this:

```
<?php
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$authid = $curauth->ID;
?>
Email: <?php echo $curauth->user_email; ?>
Website: <?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>
Name: <?php echo $curauth->user_firstname . " " . $curauth->user_lastname; ?>
Bio: <?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?>
```

Comment: If I do a print_r on the $curauth all the variables are associated with the current page information, not the user.  as such there is not value to $curauth->user_email, etc...

Comment: I would think that you need to use `var_dump($curauth)` instead of `print_r` which is used to dump an array.

Comment: var_dump($curauth) gave me the same information as when I used print_r

Comment: When I did same on my wordpress installation I got: `object(stdClass)#266 (42) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(2) "62"
  ["user_login"]=>
  string(17) "foo@example.com"
  ["user_pass"]=>
  string(34) "**********"
  ["user_nicename"]=>
  string(7) "foo"
  ["user_email"]=>
  string(17) "foo@example.com"
  ["user_url"]=>
  string(80) "https://www.example.com"
  ["user_registered"]=>
  string(19) "2008-06-10 14:07:38"
  ["user_activation_key"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["user_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["display_name"]=>
  string(15) "Foo Bar"`

Comment: hmmmm... I wonder what I am doing wrong.  BTW, thanks for your help.

Comment: I know this question haven't been active for almost two years, but I have a small problem with anubhava's solution. While creating the template in a, was successful, the page lists all the users I want, the linking does not work. I created my own author.php template, filled it up properly, yet Wordpress goes to the 404 template directly. I used the code mostly as posted, except I modified the naming to subcontractor(s) instead of member(s). Could that be the problem?

Comment: @fonix232: Please tell me which URL (link) is throwing 404 error for you?

Comment: The url is /subcontractor/[user-nicename. Since following the tutorial I tried to create a taxonomy too, without luck.

Comment: @fonix232: What is your PermaLink stricture?

Comment: The current structure is /%postname&/, but I tried various others too (/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/, /archives/%post_id%, etc). I just tried /subcontractor/%author%/, result is the same.

Comment: @fonix232: Ok can you try loading `/author/<user-nicename>` link?

Comment: Ah, fixed it. The author template was overwritten with the 404 template, that caused the problem! Wuth the /subcontractor/%author% structure, and the proper author.php, it works perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @fonix232: Now that you found this answer helped you resolving your problem. Can you upvote this answer? 1 upvote really doesn't matter much to me but I believe this answer deserves it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own templates in wordpress, 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Right, I know you can.  What I have is a page that list users, and I would like to link their name in that list to a page that will use their user id to pull in the information.  The author.php file collects the user id through have_posts(), which in this case the user will not have any posts or is an author to any posts.